# Heisenberg Inequality for $L^2$ functions

Tags: limits, inequality, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sequence-of-function

Suppose that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and its $L^2$ derivative exists, call it, $f'$, i.e $$\lim_{y\to 0} \Bigg|\Bigg|\frac{f(x-y)-f(x)}{y}-f'(x)\Bigg|\Bigg|_{L^2} = 0$$ Then $$\Big|\Big|f\Big|\Big|_{L^2}^4 \leqslant 4\Big|\Big|xf(x)\Big|\Big|_{L^2}^2 \cdot\Big|\Big|f'(x)\Big|\Big|_{L^2}^2$$ This has been asked a few times here but I couldn't find a rigorous proof that shows the above for complex-valued-$L^2$ functions.

I am able to show this for Schwartz functions using integration by parts and tried using a density argument to extend it to all of $L^2$.

We can pick a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of Schwartz functions such that $f_n\to f$ and $f_n' \to f'$ in $L^2$. But to conclude I need to show $xf_n(x)\to xf(x)$ in $L^2$. How can I show this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ has support in some large ball, say $(-R,R)$, this follows simply from

$$ \Vert x (f_n-f)\Vert_{L^2} \leq 1.000000001 R \Vert f_n -f\Vert_{L^2} \rightarrow 0 $$

for $n\rightarrow \infty$ (we need some coefficient larger than $1$ in front of $R$ as the support of $f_n$ might be slightly larger than the support of $f$, pick your favourite number larger than $1$. I did not want to go for $2$ as one might get the wrong idea that this factor $2$ has anything to do with the length of $(-R,R)$).

Now for a general $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with your conditions, pick $\chi_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0\leq \chi_n \leq 1$, $\vert \chi'_n\vert \leq 2$, $\chi_n(x) = 0$ for $\vert x \vert \geq n+1$ and $\chi_n(x)=1$ for $\vert x \vert \leq n$ (i.e. pick a bump function). Then consider $f_n = \chi_n f$. Note that we know from the first step that your inequality holds true for $f_n$. Then $\Vert xf_n \Vert_{L^2} \rightarrow \Vert x f\Vert_{L^2}$ by monotone convergence (we do not need that it is finite). We have $f_n'=\chi_n' f + \chi_n f'$. By dominated convergence we have $\chi_n' f \rightarrow 0$ in $L^2$ and by monotone convergence we have $\Vert \chi_n f' \Vert_{L^2} \rightarrow \Vert f' \Vert_{L^2}$.

Comment: Can we uniformly bound the derivatives $|\chi_n'|$ like that?

Comment: @miyagi_do We absolutely can. Pick a function $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\varphi(0)=1,$ $\varphi^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $\varphi(x)=0$ for all $\vert x \vert \geq 1$. Then we can define $$ \chi_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x\in [-n,n],\\ \varphi(x+n),& x\in (n,\infty), \\ \varphi(x-n),& x\in (-\infty,n). \end{cases} $$ Then we have $\max_{\mathbb{R}} \vert \chi_n' \vert = \max_{[-1,1]} \vert \varphi' \vert$.

Comment: In fact, we do not need infinitely many derivatives. We really only need to find a $C^2$ function $g$ such that $g(0)=1, g'(0)=0=g''(0)$ and $g^{(k)}(1)=0$ for $k\in \{0,1,2\}$. Then we reflect $g$ at the the $y$-axis and extend it by zero to get a function that we can use for $\varphi$. For our purpose we don't really care about the exact bound, just that it is uniform, so you can pick pretty much anything you like. You can use splines to such a $g$.